# Enumeration Output Error

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Apple { 

    Jonathan,GoldenDel,RedDel,Winesap,Cortland

}

class  EnumDemo{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Apple ap;

        ap=Apple.RedDel;

        System.out.println("Value of ap:" + ap);
        System.out.println();

        ap=Apple.GoldenDel;


        if(ap==Apple.GoldenDel)

            System.out.println("ap contains GoldenDel.\n");

    }
}
```

I can't have any outputs when ı use enum type.Why?

Comment: I ran this program locally and it seemed to run OK. Can you elaborate what you mean by "I can't have any outputs when ı use enum type."? What output are you getting? And what output do you expect to get?

Comment: System.out.println("Value of ap:" + ap); OUTPUT=Value of ap:RedDel

Comment: Same here. @FurkanAktaş what are you getting for it?

Comment: I can take nothing.File name is Apple.Same name with enum type.Is it a problem for it?

Comment: Making your enum static lets you use just the type without the enumname before

Comment: you mean that the code (with main) is in a Apple.java file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enum class `Apple` and your normal class `EnumDemo` both are public and they are in same file. Put them in different file and compile, then it should work Or Consider changing the access specifier or static type of enum `Apple`if you want to accommodate them in the same file.

Answer (score 4):

File Name must be same as public class name. Please rename it with EnumDemo.java and change EnumDemo class visibility to public.